# Как добавить коллизию на объект по форме объекта в Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

В игре есть объект, у которого непримитивная форма. Нужно добавить коллизию, которая соответствовала бы этой форме. Как можно реализовать подобное?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [MeshCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html), который коллайдер создаст основываясь на меше объекта. Но такое решение будет работать намного медленнее примитивов.